# Different first page header for ALL sections in MS Word 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

Here's my problem. I have a work with several chapters. Each chapter is in a separate section. In each section on the Odd Page there is the Chapter number displayed and on the Even Page the chapter title.

However, on the *first* page of *every* chapter I do *not* want to display anything. I set the Different First Page option, however this seems to work only for the very first page of the document, not each section.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Where did you get Word 2012?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's 2010.

Comment: You got me a little excited ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the meantime.

The trick is to used "Next page" breaks instead of "Continuous" breaks. When using continuous breaks only sections are separated, while with next page breaks chapter like sections can be created with separate first pages for each new section.